# What does $\lim\limits_{x\to\pi/6}\frac{1-\sqrt{3}\tan x}{\pi-6x}$ evaluate to?

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry

What does $$\lim_{x\to\pi/6}\frac{1-\sqrt{3}\tan x}{\pi-6x}$$ evaluate to? This very likely needs substitution.

Comment: This needs L'Hopital (pardon my French).

Comment: @Arjang Please do **not** edit titles to remove all non-TeX entities ([relevant meta post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9730/43351) - point 2).

Comment: I wonder why don't you use Mathematica or [wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%281-%E2%88%9A3+tan%28x%29%29%2F%28%CF%80-6x%29+as+x+approaches+%CF%80%2F6)?

Comment: @Ali ?? Because most lecturers in most decent universities/colleges won't even consider checking such a question's answer without proper explanation?!

Comment: @DonAntonio Fair, but then the question would be what is a proper way of finding this limit, rather than just: "What does $some limit$ evaluate to?"

Comment: @Lord_Farin : okeidokey :) , just doing it to have the concise side links.

Answer (score 7):

We establish that the limit

$$\lim_{x\to\pi/6}\frac{1-\sqrt{3}\tan x}{\pi-6x}$$

is of the indeterminate form $\dfrac00$; since numerator and denominator are differentiable, let us attempt De l'Hôpital's rule. It works:

$$\lim_{x\to\pi/6}\frac{1-\sqrt{3}\tan x}{\pi-6x} = \lim_{x\to\pi/6}\frac{-\sqrt3 \frac1{\cos^2 x}}{-6} = \frac{\sqrt3}6\cdot \frac43 = \frac{2\sqrt3}9$$

Comment: I like the "It works" comment. :)

Answer (score 5):

An idea with quite some trigonometry and algebra **but without l'Hospital** (not that there's something wrong with that, of course): substitute

$$y=x-\frac\pi6\iff x= y+\frac\pi6\;,\;\;\text{and}\;\;x\to\frac\pi6\implies y\to 0$$

so that our function now  is

$$\begin{align*}&-\frac16\frac{1-\sqrt 3\tan\left(y+\frac\pi6\right)}{y}=\\
=&-\frac16\frac{1-\sqrt3\frac{\tan y+\frac1{\sqrt3}}{1-\frac1{\sqrt3}\tan y}}{y}\stackrel {\color{blue}{(*)}}=\\
=&-\frac16\frac{\rlap/\color{purple}1-\left(\sqrt3+\frac1{\sqrt3}\right)\tan y-\rlap /\color{purple}1}{y\left(1-\frac1{\sqrt3}\tan y\right)}\stackrel{\color{blue}{(**)}}=\\
=&\frac16\frac{4\tan y}{y\left(\sqrt3-\tan y\right)}=\end{align*}$$
$$=\frac16\frac{\tan y}y\frac4{\sqrt3-\tan y}\color{red}{\xrightarrow[y\to 0]{}}\frac16\cdot 1\cdot\frac4{\sqrt3}=\frac2{3\sqrt3}=\frac{2\sqrt3}9$$

$${}$$

$$\begin{align*}\;\;&(*)\;\;\frac{a-b\frac cd}{e}=\frac{ad-bc}{de}\\{}\\
\;\;&(**)\;\;\text{Factor out $\,\frac1{\sqrt3}\,$ in numerator and denominator and note  minus sign in numerator}\end{align*}$$

Comment: Can you please give a good Link for L Hospital's Rule Proof...

Comment: Thanks @Lord_Farin, I shall edit it. By the 2nd equality you mean from the first line to the 2nd. one?

Comment: @Ekaveera, google " l'Hospital's Rule ". There are more than 2.5 million links...

Comment: @DonAntonio Much better, thanks for the effort.

Comment: @Lord_Farin, thank you for your first comment. No matter how much experience one may have, sometimes things don't come out as clear as one believes and it's good to have backup for that.

Comment: I vividly remember when someone asked our Calculus I professor, at the onset of a test, if they were allowed to use l'Hôpital's rule in the test. He said: "Sure, no problem. But since we haven't covered it yet in class, you will be required to prove the rule, and all intermediate theorems, before you use it.". Thanks for going the extra mile of working it out the hard way.

Answer (score 4):

By the L'Hôpital theorem
$$\lim_{x\to\pi/6}\frac{1-\sqrt{3}\tan x}{\pi-6x}=\lim_{x\to\pi/6}\frac{-\sqrt{3}(1+\tan^2 x)}{-6}=\frac{2\sqrt{3}}{9}$$

Comment: 't Seems we have different preferences for expressing the derivative of $\tan x$. :)

Comment: @Lord_Farin I just  want avoid the \frac{}{} :)

Comment: Well-done, Sami.

Answer (score 1):

without L-hospital law
$$\lim_{x\to\dfrac \pi6}\frac{1-\sqrt{3}\tan x}{\pi-6x}$$
$$\lim_{(x-\dfrac \pi6)\to 0}\frac{1-\sqrt{3}\dfrac {\sin x}{\cos x}}{6\left(\dfrac\pi 6-x\right)}$$
$$\lim_{(x-\dfrac \pi6)\to 0}\dfrac{1\cdot\cos x-\sqrt{3} \cdot{\sin x}}{6\left(\dfrac\pi 6-x\right)\cos x}$$
$$\lim_{(x-\dfrac \pi6)\to 0}2\dfrac{\dfrac12\cdot\cos x-\dfrac {\sqrt{3}}{2} \cdot{\sin x}}{6\left(\dfrac\pi 6-x\right)\cos x}$$
$$\lim_{(x-\dfrac \pi6)\to 0}2\dfrac {\sin \dfrac\pi6\cdot\cos x-\cos \dfrac \pi6 \cdot{\sin x}}{6\left(\dfrac\pi 6-x\right)\cos x}$$
$$\lim_{(x-\dfrac \pi6)\to 0}\dfrac {\sin\left(\dfrac \pi6-x\right)}{3\left(\dfrac\pi 6-x\right)\cos x}$$

since $$\lim_{x\to a} \dfrac {\sin a}{a}=1$$
$$\lim_{(x-\dfrac \pi6)\to 0}\dfrac {1}{3\cos \dfrac \pi6}$$
$$\dfrac{2}{3\sqrt3}\implies \dfrac {2\sqrt3}{9}$$

Comment: +1 Very nice. Instead of "normal" parentheses try to use " \left(...\right) " so that parentheses will fit themselves to appropiate size.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{1-\sqrt{3}\tan x}{\pi-6x}=\frac{\sqrt3}6\cdot\frac{\tan \frac\pi6-\tan x }{\frac\pi6-x}\left(\text{ as }\tan\frac\pi6=\frac1{\sqrt3}\right)$$
$$=\frac{\sqrt3}6\cdot\frac{\sin\left(\frac\pi6-x\right)}{\left(\frac\pi6-x\right)\cos x\cos \frac\pi6}$$

$$\lim_{x\to\frac\pi6}\frac{1-\sqrt{3}\tan x}{\pi-6x}=\frac{\sqrt3}{6\cos \frac\pi6}\cdot\lim_{x\to\frac\pi6}\frac{\sin\left(\frac\pi6-x\right)}{\left(\frac\pi6-x\right)}\frac1{\lim_{x\to\frac\pi6}\cos x}$$
$$=\frac{\sqrt3}{6\cos\frac\pi6}\cdot\lim_{y\to0}\frac{\sin y}y\cdot\frac1{\cos\frac\pi6}$$ (Putting $\frac\pi6-x=y$ in the first limit)

$$\lim_{x\to\frac\pi6}\frac{1-\sqrt{3}\tan x}{\pi-6x}= \frac{\sqrt3}{6\cos^2\frac\pi6}=\frac2{3\sqrt3}$$

---

$$\text{In fact, }\lim_{x\to a}\frac {f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}=f'(a)$$

$$\implies \lim_{x\to a}\left(\frac {\tan x-\tan a}{x-a}\right)=\left(\frac {d\tan x}{dx}\right)_{x=a}=\sec^2a$$

$$\implies \lim_{x\to \frac\pi6}\left(\frac {\tan x-\frac1{\sqrt3}}{x-\frac\pi6}\right)=\sec^2\frac\pi6=\frac43$$

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why others used L'Hospital's rule but it's not necessary here. It works wonderfully but you (OP) may not yet be familiar with the technique. The limit is very close to being the definition of the derivative. We can rewrite it as

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow \frac{\pi}{6}}\frac{\sqrt{3}}{6}\frac{\tan x-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}}{x-\frac{\pi}{6}}.$$

The latter half of this is, in fact, just the definition of the derivative of $\tan x$ defined at $\frac{\pi}{6}$. Since we know what the derivative of it is, we can quickly write down the answer: $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{6}\left(\sec\left(\frac{\pi}{6}\right)\right)^2$.

Hopefully you can reduce this further.

Comment: First, whe nyou posted your answer, it already was one hour after iostrema007 and 5 hours after I myself posted both proofs without using l'Hospital's rule...second, arguing by means of l'H or by means of some function's derivative is pretty close.